# Unity - How can I control fog color based on skybox color?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I have a gradient on a skybox, and I want the terminal fog color to be the same as the sky color behind the object that is being occluded. But it still needs to be fog and respect distance.

I see one way of doing it without actually using fog, with a gradient of my choosing on a skybox. The skybox gets masked out by the depth map, and then overlaid onto the non-sky geometry. You would be able to look down into the depths, and the blackness below gets darker gradually like a "fog" because it is masked by the depth operation. Look up and see the same phenomenon with the lighter color. Basically control "fog" terminal color by camera angle.

What would be the best way to implement this, and could it be performant on mobile devices?